# How can i install skype in genymotion?

Tags: android, genymotion

I am trying to learn skype uri.Now i use genymotion.To use it i have to install skype in genymotion.But going in playstore from skype it is saying that  your device is not compatible with the version.I am using genymotion version 2.2.2.Cany anyone help me??

Answer (score 2):

1.To run the latest version of Skype for Android (Skype 5), you'll need to have Android OS version 4.0 or above. If you're running Android OS 2.3 and above, you can run Skype 4 for Android.

You have 2.2.2.

2.You will also need to know what type of processor your device has. If you're not sure, check the device's user manual, or contact its manufacturer. For the following processors:

Gemymotion is based on x86, not on ARM.

If you still want install skype to Genymotion :

- install to genymotion GENYMOTION_ARM_TRANSTATION. (download here :
  http://filetrip.net/dl?4SUOrdcMRv) and just drag&drop to running
  genymotion and press always OK.
- adb reboot
- adb install com.skype.raider.apk

Comment: I´m getting the same message, but I'm using the VM for LG Optimus III, which has Android 4.1.1. Any idea? Thanks in advance